# Save to database function isn't working when called from another function

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

Everything is working except when i call the save_info function from load_info function to save to database
 I tried including the entire block of code from the save_info function in the if statement but it still doesn't work

```html
// This function will save information to an existing account
//==MAN8==
function save_info($dbh, $table, $pname, $pip, $pnp, $pop, $psp)
{
try
 {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $table SET p_ip=?, p_np=?,p_op=?,p_sp=? WHERE p_name=?");
  $stmt->execute(array($pip,$pnp,$pop,$psp,$pname));
  echo "1";
 }
 catch (PDOExecption $ex)
  { 
   echo "0";
  }
 $dbh = null;
}

// This function will pull account information
//==MAN9==
function load_info($dbh,$table,$pname)
{
 {
  $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE p_name = '$pname'");
  $result = $stmt->fetchObject();
  
  if ($result->p_ip > $result->p_np)
  {
  echo 'yes';
  }
     if ($result->p_ip = $result->p_np)
  {
  save_info($dbh, $table, $pname, $pip, $pnp, $pop, $psp); 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: `$result->p_ip = $result->p_np` will always be true. You also should parameterize everywhere

Comment: ($result->p_ip = $result->p_np) was greater than not equal to and it still wouldn't save to database.I even tried a different value in it's place

Comment: Yeah maybe, but your comparison operator is actually an assignment (`=` instead of `==`)

Comment: Change to (==) and now it inserts null into the database

Comment: Your `$pip, $pnp, $pop, $psp` in your function call are all undefined. Are your functions inside a class, ie class method, requiring `$this->save_info(...)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention before ($pip, $pnp, $pop, $psp) are variables created before hand